# iAd doesn't hide when it fails to load?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iad

This seems like the dumbest question ever, but after wading through all of Apple's documentation and the useless online tutorials, I still can't figure out how to properly implement `iAds` into my application. So, my app starts off in a table view controller, and I have an `iAd` object underneath the navigation bar and above the table.

Now, in my code: (I also have the iAd framework added)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MasterTableViewController : UITableViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet ADBannerView *iAd;
}
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBannerLoaded) BOOL bannerLoaded;
@end
```

then in the .m file

```
#import "MasterTableViewController.h"

@interface MasterTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation MasterTableViewController
@synthesize bannerLoaded;

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    if (!willLeave)
    {
        // nothing in this case thanks to ARC 
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    iAd.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    iAd.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)
    {
        if (bannerLoaded)
        {
            iAd.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            iAd.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when I test the app without internet connection the `iAd` does not load (obviously) BUT it also does not hide. So, at the top of the screen I'm left with a big white rectangle. Otherwise, the ad works fine when a connection is available. Does anyone have any ideas? Also - I just added the endless loops to see if they made a difference, those were completely on purpose lol.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have added your ADBannerView via the Storyboard as I can't see where you initialise the banner position.

1. In storyboard, set the initial location just off screen.
2. In "bannerViewDidLoadAd", animate the banner into view.
3. In "bannerView: didFailToReceiveAdWithError:", animate the banner out of view.

There is a good example here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

Hope this helps.  I have just implemented this but don't have access to my code at the moment.

It does bring up some errors in the simulator but works fine on a device.

I have tested this on iOS6 and works ok even if an iAd is displayed then the user loses the connection (so it looks like "bannerView: didFailToReceiveAdWithError:" is being called for me).

Answer (score 0):

You have a property `bannerLoaded` for saving the state of your Ad, which is good.

At the very first, in your `viewDidLoad` method, iAd can't be loaded, so you have to set your property accordingly : `self.bannerLoaded = NO;`

Then, when you receive / fail to receive your ad, you need to update this property.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerLoaded) {
        iAd.hidden = NO;
        self.bannerLoaded = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    if (self.bannerLoaded) {
        iAd.hidden = YES;
        self.bannerLoaded = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue :(. When I disconnect from all data and test the app, I still get the white rectangle.

Comment: Actually, i don't think that `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` is getting called when there's no internet connection. You will have to implement some other methods to handle internet connection check. Take a look at `Reachability` library, provided by Apple : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Well, I spent the past hour or so searching to figure out an answer and I think I've come up with a solution. I don't believe the reachability class is involved but I can't say that for sure :P. So, I gave it a shot on the iOS simulator, and it worked a lot different. It gave me errors saying my banners didn't have a delegate. So, in the ViewDidLoad I did: iAd.delegate = self; and re ran it and it seemed to work as expected. I then tested it on the my iPhone and  after a few minutes it worked as expected. I think the testing on the iPhone sort of messed it up. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Oh right the delegate ! Sorry, i didn't think about it. I'm glad you make it worked at the end :)

Comment: The problem now is I can't figure out the logic on this thing. I have the visible ad rate at 80% but after it cycles through a fail it makes the ad go white again. Any ideas?

Comment: --Update-- When it "loads" fine, but after is crashes the add is hidden (as it should) but the ad is never "loaded" again. I'm using the same logic as your code above if that helps :P.